# My UIImage is loaded but doesn't appear on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

i'm writing an app that changes an image through different conditions. When i debug everything is set but i do not see the image on my screen. Can anybody please help me?

```
-(void)setLuminanceImageSource

{
    self.luminanceImageView.image = nil;
    UIImage *image;
    switch (self.luminanceImageSource) {
        case FULL_LIGHT:
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"belichting-goed"];
            [self.luminanceImageView setImage:image];
            NSLog(@"full");
            break;
        case HALF_LIGHT:
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"belichting-matig"];
            [self.luminanceImageView setImage:image];
            NSLog(@"half");
            break;
        case BAD_LIGHT:
            image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"belichting-slecht"];
            [self.luminanceImageView setImage:image];
            NSLog(@"bad");
            break;
        default:
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"belichting-goed"];
            break;
    }
    [self.luminanceImageView setImage:image];
    [self.luminanceImageView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.view addSubview:self.luminanceImageView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.luminanceImageView];
}
```

This is my method that controls the image. I have an UIImageView in the .xib file and when i run the app i see the image i have selected in attribute inspector, but it disappears when this method is called.

EDIT: I have changed the names to the conventional naming style.

This is my debug-console, the image object is not nil but the `luminanceImageView` stays `nil`.
[image: debug-console]

I have created a github repository where i cloned my project in so you can see my code. 
[CameraApp repository](https://github.com/woudwijk84/CameraApp.git)
Only difference is the location of the luminaceImageView, now it is located in the middle of the screen so i can be sure that it is in view of the device.

Comment: check your image name extension.. is it `png` ?? or not ?

Comment: why you are calling this [self.luminanceImage setNeedsDisplay]; UIImageView class (and it's sublasses) don't call drawRect if you call their setNeedsDisplay. thats why you are not getting frame for your imageview

Comment: @iPatel, yes it is. Should i place that after the name? EDIT: i used this option and still no image..

Comment: @pawan, even when i do not use [self.luminanceImage setNeedsDisplay]; i do not see my image. But thanks for your reaction.

Comment: First & foremost use `{}` with every `case` statement.
Secondly, try using proper naming conventions, such as `luminanceImageView` & not `luminanceImage`.

Also add the subview first & then set the image of the imageview(ideally I do not feel this will make a difference, but you can give a try).

Comment: If your imageView which If I am not mistaken that is "luminanceImage" is in the .xib file, then why are you adding it again to self.view. Though it is not related to the question that you have asked but it can help me understanding the problem.

Comment: @footyapps27 there is absolutely no reason to add { and } to case statements - those are only needed when you define and use local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that:

> the image object is not nil but the luminanceImageView stays nil.

Of course, you need to create the image view first, before you can set its image. The easiest in your case is probably to create it and set its image in one go, and then add it to your view:

```
self.luminanceImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.view addSubview:self.luminanceImageView];
```

EDIT (after looking at the GitHub): 
You currently set the view like this:

```
self.luminanceImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[self.luminanceImageView setImage:image];
```

That means that if you set it in the xib (I have not checked that), then you override it here.
There are three problems with this:

1. the luminanceImageView still needs to be added to your view, as I
   already stated above
2. the plain init creates an imageView with
   size (0, 0). This is unlike the initWithImage:, which creates a imageView with the size of the image.
3. the setImage: does not resize the imageView. From the
   [UIWebView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_9):

> Setting the image property does not change the size of a UIImageView. Call sizeToFit to adjust the size of the view to match the image.

If you have correctly set the imageView with its size in the XIB, then leave out everything else and just do:

```
[self.luminanceImageView setImage:image];
```

If the size is not correct, then follow this with:

```
[self.luminanceImageView sizeToFit];
```

EDIT (after debugging the code):

Your problem is that you set the image from a background thread. Almost all view operation in iOS need to be done from the main thread. Doing like this solves your problem:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.luminanceImageView setImage:image];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.luminanceImageView];
});
```

BTW, you also change self.layer in your code. That is probably not a good idea and may lead to problems later. Use a separate view for the camera, and use [cameraView.layer addSublayer:newLayer] to get around that.

Comment: thanks for your replay. I tried your solution but it didn't work for me. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Of course, you still need to add it to your view, which you show in the example code, but not in the console picture, so it is unclear what you are actually doing. Or do you mean that self.luminanaceImageView is still nil after this??

Comment: i created the `luminanceImageView` in a `.xib` file, connected it to the correct view. I am not sure how i did it but the object is not `nil` anymore but i still can't see it on my screen. I've added my project to a github repository which i added in the question above so you can see my code.

Comment: That was my first try, but somehow it doesn't work. But i was able to make the image appear when i put this code:`UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"belichting-slecht"];
 [self.luminanceImageView setImage:image];` to a button that toggles the flashlight on and off. but i do not want it to be set with a button. So i don't really know what is the problem in my code..

Comment: Then your problem is definitely with luminanceImageView. Check in the debugger that everything I have mentioned is done: The luminanceImageView is not nil, its superview is self.view, its size is correct, its image property is set and is an image with correct size.

Comment: When i log the values i get these results:
`<UIImage: 0x15661500>
luminanceImageView frame origin X:140.000000, Y:58.000000;
luminanceImageView size X:40.000000, Y:40.000000;
view frame origin X:0.000000, Y:0.000000;
view frame size X:320.000000, Y:568.000000;
window <UIWindow: 0x156425c0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); 
autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x15642c90>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x156426f0>>`
So i see nothing wrong with it..

Comment: I was intrigued, and decided to download the github and do some debugging for you. See updated answer for what was wrong. Blij dat ik een landgenoot kon helpen!

Answer (score 0):

try this edit from your code

```
-(void)setLuminanceImageSource
{
[self.sess stopRunning];
//[self.layer removeFromSuperlayer];

UIImage *image;
switch (self.luminanceImageSource) {
    case FULL_LIGHT:
    {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"belichting-goed.png"];
        NSLog(@"full");
        break;
    }
    case HALF_LIGHT:
    {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"belichting-matig.png"];
        NSLog(@"half");
        break;
    }
    case BAD_LIGHT:
    {
        image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"belichting-slecht.png"];
        NSLog(@"bad");
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"belichting-goed.png"];
        break;
    }
}
[self.luminanceImageView setImage:image];
[self.layer addSublayer: self.luminanceImageView.layer];
//[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.luminanceImageView];
//  NSLog(@"%@", self.luminanceImageView.image);
//  NSLog(@"lumi X:%f, Y:%f", self.luminanceImageView.frame.origin.x,    self.luminanceImageView.frame.origin.y);
//  NSLog(@"view X:%f, Y:%f",self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y);
//  NSLog(@"window %@", self.view.window);
}
```

Comment: My only other comment would be to add either a log or an assert just before the last statement, to insure that image is not nil. Also can use a more direct statement: `self. luminanceImage = image;` - more modern syntax.

Comment: @DavidH  luminanceImage(bad naming convention) is a UIImageView. so it should be self.luminanceImage.image=image;

Comment: @DavidH, i have used the debugger to check if it was nil or not and it is not nil. I could even see the correct image when clicked on the eye-icon of the variable in the debug-console.

Comment: @Woudwijk84 can you paste whole code of your controller. it looks like you are setting nil on self.luminanceImage.

Comment: @pawan, i have over 800 lines of code in this class and this method is  basically all that i have for filling this image. The only thing i have is "@synthesize luminanceImageView;" and in the .h file i have "@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *luminanceImageView;". And the .xib file where i made the UIImageView. I tried to add a screenshot from my debug-console but i lack one reputation-point to send that screenshot.

Comment: you dont have a IBOutlet on this @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *luminanceImageView; ? check is it connected with xib.

Comment: @Woudwijk84 in your code you have written luminanceImage , instead luminanceImageView.

Comment: Well, another good point - add a log or assert on `self.luminanceImageView`, to insure it's not nil. Additionally, NSLog the image view, the view's superView, its window, frame, the image.size. Yeah, it takes time - but you got to dig if the problem is not something really simple. Also, failing everything else, create a small demo project, post it on Dropbox etc. if you spend some time and answer some questions, and get some point, you could offer a bounty for an answer - that gets you lots and lots of attention. Are you using constraints? The imageView may be offscreen or have a size of 0,0.

Comment: @pawan, i did had an `IBOutlet` on the `@property` but that also didn't work so i tried it without. It is connected with the correct views. And i refactored to `luminaceImageView`, forgot to change one name in the code-snippet

Comment: @Woudwijk84 form your updated post with the image of your debugger I can see that luminanceImageView is nil. How did you set it up? If its in the storyboard/xib you need the IBOutlet.

Comment: @BooRanger, i did set it up from a .xib and now i am using a `IBOutlet` which i connected to the correct view.

Comment: @Woudwijk84 without checking code , i cant say what you are missing. put your code for this controller only on dropbox or somewhere & post a link here. so i can check.

Comment: @pawan, i've created a github repository so you can see my code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @pawan, can't see modified code. Just my own commits.

Comment: here on stack overflow , i have just updated the code for setLuminanceImageSource here.

Comment: @pawan, i checked your code, but now the camera stops because of `[self.sess stoprunning]` if you start the session again the camera will stutter. And i still don't see the `luminaneImageView`. But thanks for looking in to it.